# function oracle to postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm migrating an Oracle database to PostgreSQL, to transfer the tables I had no problem, however I'm having trouble transcribing a function for it to run in Postgres, below the function found in Oracle:

```
create or replace FUNCTION  "FN_HOUR_MINUTE" (P_HOUR IN NUMBER) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS
  -- PL/SQL Specification
  V_RETORN                 NUMBER(4);
  -- Convert hour to minute
  -- PL/SQL Block
BEGIN
V_RETORN := 60*TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(P_HOUR,'0000'),' ') ,1,2))+
                  TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(P_HOUR, '0000'),' '), 3,2));

RETURN V_RETORN;
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
       RETURN NULL ;
END;
```

I tried writing in postgres as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_hour_minute(p_hour in NUMERIC)
  RETURNS NUMERIC(4) AS $$
DECLARE
  v_retorn NUMERIC(4);
BEGIN
  v_retorn := 60*TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(p_hour,'0000'),' ') ,1,2))+
                   TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(p_hour, '0000'),' '), 3,2));
  RETURN v_retorn;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But gives an error that says the to_number function does not exist.

Comment: try `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(p_hour,'0000'),' ') ,1,2), '0000')`  Also, why are you converting to character then to number?

Comment: It worked, thank you.
I did not quite understand why he did these two conversions, the Oracle database was not made by me, but that function worked there in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the formating for the `TO_NUMBER` section.  Update the `TO_NUMBER` to `TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(LTRIM(TO_CHAR(p_hour,'0000'),' ') ,1,2), '0000')` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you spread the expression into factors:

```
select TO_CHAR(1234,'0000'),
    ltrim(TO_CHAR(1234,'0000')),
    substr(ltrim(TO_CHAR(1234,'0000')),1,2),
    substr(ltrim(TO_CHAR(1234,'0000')),3,2)
from dual;

TO_CH LTRIM SU SU
----- ----- -- --
 1234 1234  12 34
```

you will see that this is just a very advanced way to calculate such an expression

```
60 * TRUNC( p_hour / 100 ) + p_hour % 100
```